# Mandatory App update in windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have made an update for windows store app as a mandatory update. In my application I have checked weather an update is a mandatory update or not.In some machines it shows as a mandatory update and in some machines it shown as not a mandatory update. What could be the reason for it?.

Answer (score 0):

You [mandatory update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#make-a-package-submission-mandatory-in-the-dev-center-dashboard) settings only apply to UWP packages for customers running Windows 10, version 1607 or later.

So you might check the OS version of the machine in which it shows as a non-mandatory update. Additionally, please also note the day and time when the package update becomes mandatory.
[image]

Comment: Both have same OS version,and i have checked after publishing. Store version will make any Impact?.

Comment: The machine which shows as mandatory update is of version 14393 (new laptops).Some machine have same OS version with Updated manually.

Comment: @Vishnu So what version of the Store you use to update manually?

Comment: And what is the device type?

Comment: Its Laptop.I have downloaded the OS from Insider preview.

Answer (score 0):

*"Shown as mandatoy update"* - in there store or do you have some own logic that displays whether it's mandatory or not? For there shouldn't be any hint from MS except when talking to the update API.

> The mandatory status of a package update is not enforced by Microsoft, and the OS does not provide a UI to indicate to users that a mandatory app update must be installed. Developers are intended to use the mandatory setting to enforce mandatory app updates in their own code.

[Source (bottom)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates)

Also Mattew is right, it only works for versions *gte* 1607 .